# left join fetch of nullable grandchild association causes NPE in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have an entity called Foo.  It has a nullable many-to-one association to Bar.  Bar has a non-nullable many-to-one association to Baz.

My goal is to grab all Foo entities and eagerly fetch their Bar associations and, for those foo where foo.bar is non-null, eagerly fetch foo.bar.baz.

Is this possible?  The following both cause hibernate to throw a NullPointerException inside its query engine:

```
select f from Foo f left join fetch f.bar left join fetch f.bar.baz

select f from Foo f left join fetch f.bar.baz
```

Now, this works:

```
select f from Foo left join fetch f.bar
```

But that doesn't eagerly fetch f.bar.baz for those f with non-null bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias `bar` in your query:

```
select f from Foo f
  left join fetch f.bar b
  left join fetch b.baz
```

Comment: Does the second fetch need to be an outer join if the association from Bar to Baz is non-null?

Comment: Theoretically - no. Practically, unless the resulting SQL is generated as `join ... on ... ` rather than `join ... where ... `, I've seen weird behavior in some RDBMS. Try it for whatever RDBMS you need to support and see if it works.

Comment: one last question:  if i want to use baz in the where clause, is a better way to do that than using a sub-query, e.g.

select f from Foo f
  left join fetch f.bar b 
  left join fetch b.baz
where f in (
  select x from Foo x where x.bar.baz = 'ABC'
)

Comment: add an alias to baz and refer to it in a query - `select f from Foo f
 left join fetch f.bar b left join fetch b.baz bz where bz.property = 'value'`. Or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?